# Trying to fix SKU numbers from 55A_3 to A55_3 with PHP in SQL

Tags: php, arrays, replace, sku

I have SKU numbers imported from a CSV file into SQL DB.
Pattern look like:

```
55A_3  
345W_1+04B_1  
128T_2+167T_2+113T_8+115T_8
```

I am trying to move all the letters in front of the numbers.
like:

```
A55_3  
W345_1+B04_1  
T128_2+T167_2+T113_8+T115_8
```

My best idea how to do it was to search for 345W and so, and to replace it with W345 and so:

```
$sku = "345W_1+04B_1";

$B_range_num = range(0,400);
$B_range_let = range("A","Z");
```

then generating the find and replace arrays

```
$B_find = 
$B_replace =
```

maybe just using str_replace??

```
$res = str_replace($B_find,$B_replace,$sku);
```

Result should be for all SKU numbers
W345_1+B04_1
Any ideas?

Comment: Are the SKU numbers static or dynamic? Meaning are there many different combinations of SKU numbers?

Comment: [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on `+`, then on `_`, then separate/reverse the two components, [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on `_` and `+`. Do not pursue what you've got right now, and if you ever find yourself having to generate all possible combinations of something you're almost certainly on the wrong track.

Comment: Many different, but use same pattern 2-3x numbers + 1x letter + slash + number(pcs) 1-100. I am executing a function, while printing the results from DB. ".cleanSKU($mrow['custom_label'],$mrow['seller_id'])." then function cleanSKU($sku,$seller) {

Comment: Sammitch, some SKUs are like 55A_3 or just 55A, if there is second SKU for same sale, then + can be seen, but sometimes is space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I defined a method with specific format with unlimited length.

```
$str = '128T_2+167T_2+113T_8+115T_8';

echo convertProductSku($str);

function convertProductSku($str) {
  $arr = [];
  $parts = explode('+', $str);

  foreach ($parts as $part) {
    list($first, $second) = array_pad(explode('_', $part), 2, null);
    $letter = substr($first, -1);
    $number = substr($first, 0, -1);

    $arr[] = $letter . $number . ($second ? '_' . $second : '');
  }

  return implode('+', $arr);
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to accommodate 55A concepts based on your comment in the above question section.

Comment: Work like a charm

Comment: I am going to use your code for taking out how many pcs from selected sku was sold, which is next stage. Thanks you! For the topic I was posted, Nick`s code looks more simple and will use it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do this job, looking for some digits, followed by a letters and one of an `_` with digits, a `+` or end of string, and then swapping the order of the digits and letters:

```
$skus = array('55A_3', 
              '345W_1+04B_1',
              '128T_2+167T_2+113T_8+115T_8',
              '55A');
foreach ($skus as &$sku) {
    $sku = preg_replace('/(\d+)([A-Z]+)(?=_\d+|\+|$)/', '$2$1', $sku);
}
print_r($skus);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A55_3
    [1] => W345_1+B04_1
    [2] => T128_2+T167_2+T113_8+T115_8
    [3] => A55
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kfMdC)

Comment: Your preg_replace doesn't work with '55A'. They do not specify this in the question, but comment about it in the comments of the question.

Comment: @blupointmedia thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't noticed it in the comments. I've updated the regex...

Comment: If you understand regex and can modify it if need be, then I would say @Nick is a better solution. I tend to not use regex in my answers, because some beginners aren't familiar with it and can follow longer versions.

Comment: If input is A55 (correct one) Nicks`s return A55, yours 5A5

Comment: @TihomirGrozev, ok, but your question didn't say anything about the correct format.